# creating input field for html form... but adding a 'label' for it as well?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, label

I have an html form. When you click the button, a javascript function adds a new field. I'm trying to have the function also add a 'label' for the field as well.

I've tried using document.createElement("LABEL"), but that doesn't let me change the innerHtml (or maybe I'm doing it wrong..), nor add a closing

Here is my code. Thanks!
    
    
        
            var instance = 2;

```
        function newTextBox(element)
        {       
            instance++; 
            // Create new input field
            var newInput = document.createElement("INPUT");
            newInput.id = "text" + instance;
            newInput.name = "text" + instance;
            newInput.type = "text";
            instance++; 

            document.body.insertBefore(document.createElement("BR"), element);
            document.body.insertBefore(newInput, element);

        }
    </script>
</head>


<body>
    <LABEL for="text1">First name: </LABEL>
    <input id="text1" type="text" name="text1">
    <LABEL for="text2">Last name: </LABEL>
    <input id="text2" type="text" name="text2">



    <input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="New text box" onclick="newTextBox(this);" />
</body>
```

Comment: post your code where you tried doing a `document.createElement('LABEL')` so we can debug it.

Comment: sorry, deleted it because I thought it was useless:
        var label = document.createElement("LABEL");
    label.htmlFor = newInput.id;
    label.value = 'First Name';

Comment: There's no such thing as `label.value`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
   function newTextBox(element)
            {               
                    instance++; 
                    // Create new input field
                    var newInput = document.createElement("INPUT");
                    newInput.id = "text" + instance;
                    newInput.name = "text" + instance;
                    newInput.type = "text";

                    var label = document.createElement("Label");

                    label.htmlFor = "text" + instance;
                    label.innerHTML="Hello";
                    instance++; 

                    document.body.insertBefore(document.createElement("BR"), element);
                    document.body.insertBefore(newInput,element);
                    document.body.insertBefore(label, newInput);
```

Note that [for](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_label_for.asp) attribute of the label tag, corresponds to the property [htmlFor](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_label_htmlfor.asp) fo the label object in javascript

Comment: You cannot use `label.for`.  The answer from Proto Bassi is correct.

Comment: Actually. Both these answers are wrong in some ways. They both advocate using innerHTML which is bad but more important, the 'for' is set using label.htmlFor

Answer (score 9):

The example from Vincent does not work.

Try this:

```
var newlabel = document.createElement("Label");
    newlabel.setAttribute("for",id_from_input);
    newlabel.innerHTML = "Here goes the text";
parentDiv.appendChild(newlabel);
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. The attribute `for` must be set using `setAttribute`.

Comment: -1 for the suggestion of dom creation and then innerHTML usage instead of document.createTextNode

Comment: @Rafe, please give an example on how you will set the type to "Label" and how you are going to set an attribute on a TextNode. I don't thing your comment is anyhow helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="somediv">
 some div
</div>

<script>

var instance = 0;

function newTextBox(element){               

instance++; 
// Create new input field
var newInput = document.createElement("INPUT");
newInput.id = "text" + instance;
newInput.name = "text" + instance;
newInput.type = "text";

var newlabel = document.createElement("Label");
newlabel.setAttribute("for","text" + instance);
newlabel.innerHTML = "Here goes the text";
document.getElementById("somediv").appendChild(newlabel);
document.getElementById("somediv").appendChild(newInput);
}

</script>
```